# Show that $f^{-1}(K)$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Exercise** Let $f\colon\Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^n$ be continuous and suppose there exists $k>0$ such that $||f(x)-f(x')|| \ge k||x-x'||$ for all $x,x'\in \Bbb{R}^n$.
>
> $i)$ Show that $f$ is injective and proper.

**proof** Let $x,y\in \Bbb{R}^n$. If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $f(x)-f(y)$. But we know that there exist $k>0$ for all $x,y\in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that

$$||f(x)-f(y) || \ge k||x-y ||$$

Therefore $k||x-y||=0$, $k\not=0$. Thus if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$ in other word $f$ is injective.

For the properness we need to show that the inverse image under $f$ of every compact set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is compact in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Let $K\subseteq\Bbb{R}^n$ be a compact subset. Thus $K$ is closed and bounded, which means that

$$f^{-1}(\Bbb{R}^n\backslash K)=f^{-1}(\Bbb{R}^n)\backslash f^{-1}(K)=\Bbb{R}^n\backslash f^{-1}(K)$$ is open. Thus $f^{-1}(K)$ is closed. And here I got stuck. Any hint about how to prove that $K$ is bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $K$ is bounded we have for all $y\in K$ that $||y||\le M$ for some $M\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose you have $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)\in K$. Then 
$$
||x|| = ||x-0||\le\frac{1}{k}||f(x) - f(0)|| \le\frac{1}{k}\left(||f(x)|| + ||f(0)||\right) \le \frac{M}{k} + \frac{||f(0)||}{k}.
$$